# error=redirect_uri_mismatch in Salesforce Mobile SDK

Tags: rest-api, mobilesdk, jquerymobile

I have created a hybrid_local mobile app with [forcedroid](https://www.npmjs.org/package/forcedroid) and was working fine with my dev org. But when I tried to run the same app with one of our company sandboxes, it's giving the below error on the emulator even without going to the salesforce log in page for the oauth process, 
**error=redirect_uri_mismatch&error_description=redirect_uri%20must%20match%20configuration**
Since I'm still playing around the sdk I believe this is because of some configuration still need to be done(error description also says btw). If anybody know about this or if it's a common mistake please be kind enough to help me out.
To call the sandbox I've configured following things so far.

1. Altered the `remoteAccessConsumerKey` at
   **assets\www\bootconfig.json** in the app
2. Altered the `remoteAccessConsumerKey` at **res\values\bootconfig.xml** in the
   sdk library

And for both the organizations the call back url is same. When I connect to dev org it's working fine. Only the difference is the consumerKey. What/ Where I need to do the missing configuration?

Thanks

Comment: Is it due to moving from login to test instance .Somewhere you need to say from login to Test i belive

Comment: Thanks for the response @MohithKumar yes, that need to be done which I tried with no luck.

Comment: Oh! it's wokring. In both orgs I had the Callback URL as "sfdc://success" but in the bootconfig files it was the default(testsfdc:///mobilesdk/detect/oauth/done). After altering it with "sfdc://success" app is working fine. Now my question need to edit. How it was worked with the default value when it connects to my dev org?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the connected app at salesforce side, the **Callback URL** was different with the `oauthRedirectURI` value in the **bootconfig.josn**. It was having the default value for the  `oauthRedirectURI` and after replacing with the salesforce connected app's Callback URL it's working fine. 
But it's confusing how it was working with the default value when I connect to my dev org.